# Unable to find a camera's IP despite scanning local network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, webcam

Lately I've been trying to find a newly installed network camera. Thankfully, I do have it's MAC address as it is listed under it. So I ran a 'sudo nmap -sn 192.168.1.0/24' scan that way I could find what IP is resolved to the MAC address. Strangely, the MAC did not appear in the scan results. I only really have 2 theories as to why this is. The first one being that for some reason the cam has an IP differing from the network subnet. The second is that the cam is using some kind of Wake on LAN or similar protocol where its only online when someone is using it.

Comment: Is the camera working? If so, do you have access to the router? Most routers will show you the Mac -> IP allocation.

Comment: In addition to what @davidgo suggested, you could also make a “DHCP reservation” in your router that binds your camera’s MAC to a fixed IP address (that you can determine yourself) in your local address range. When you’ve done that, your camera will always have the same address.